# how to display image by taking path from .js object in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Here is my index.js file where i take images.

```
export const dataList = [
  {
    category: "Arts",
    cuisine: "Bamboo",
    id: 1,
    title: "Bambooza - Bamboo Arts and Crafts",
    price: 499,
    image: "./images/bambooza_arts.png",
    rating: 5
  },
  {
    category: "Material",
    cuisine: "Bags",
    id: 2,
    title: "Recycled Eco-friendly Bag",
    price: 199,
    image: "./images/bag_2.png",
    rating: 4
  },
  {
    category: "Material",
    cuisine: "Bamboo",
    id: 3,
    title: "Bambooza Box with Lock | Eco-friendly",
    price: 199,
    image: "images/box_bamboo.png",
    rating: 3
  },
  {
    category: "Material",
    cuisine: "Cups",
    id: 4,
    title: " Biodegradable Compostable White up | Craft Double Wall | Bamboo Fiber TravelMug ",
    price: 99,
    image: "images/white_cup.png",
    rating: 5
  },
  {
    category: "Material",
    cuisine: "Recycled",
    id: 5,
    title: "Ecofriendly Chipboard Binders (3 nit) Recycled Binders |",
    price: 129,
    image: "images/binder_image.png",
    rating: 3

  },
];
```

Comment: Please add your react component as well to see what you have currently

Answer (score 0):

You can import the file and then loop it over the array and then access the image in the object and do something like this inside the loop -

`<img src={arr.image} />` assuming you named the variable inside `arr` while looping.

Answer (score 0):

map through each element in dataList and take the image path and put it in the etc like so

```js
{dataList.map(elem => {
    <img src={elem .image} alt={elem.title}/>
})}
```